# why wireshark can't track wget packet?

Tags: tcp, wireshark

When I use wireshark to track tcp packet, it works fine. But when I use `wget` command, it can't track. What's the problem ?

```
○ → wget http://superuser.com/questions/674605/what-is-type-of-icmp-packets-tcp-or-udp
--2016-10-01 10:50:36--  http://superuser.com/questions/674605/what-is-type-of-icmp-packets-tcp-or-udp
Resolving superuser.com... 151.101.193.69, 151.101.1.69, 151.101.65.69, ...
Connecting to superuser.com|151.101.193.69|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 74235 (72K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘what-is-type-of-icmp-packets-tcp-or-udp’

what-is-type-of-icmp-packets-tcp-or-udp       100%[==============================================================================================>]  72.50K  37.3KB/s    in 1.9s

2016-10-01 10:50:39 (37.3 KB/s) - ‘what-is-type-of-icmp-packets-tcp-or-udp’ saved [74235/74235]
```

And wireshark gets nothing:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, because I use VPN which causes the dest ip changed to VPN address .